# Issue with updating Wokitem status using WorkItem Updater

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using WorkItem Updater task in pipeline to update workitems automatically onces deloyment is done in release pipeline.

But I am getting "No workitems found to update" message but there is a workitem linked with build & release and it is not updating.

could anyone please give me pointer to resolve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Issue with updating Wokitem status using WorkItem Updater

I have test this extension on my side, and it works fine.

Since you do not share the configuration of your task and the info of the linked workitem, I could only provide you the troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue or you could update your question with those info.

As test demo, I have set the WorkItem Updater like below:

[image]

Then I created a workitem and set the state to Active.

Enable the CI for the pipeline and modify the file in the repo, submit the change with link the new created workitem.

The build will be triggered and the build log shows it successful:

[image]

So, if you get the message "No workitems found to update", please make sure the linked workitem match the filter for the configuration of your task.

Comment: Thank you @Leo for the above pointer.
Today, I had done In-depth troubleshooting and found that previously I was using pipeline artifact due to which work items are updated as expected using WorkItem Updater with proper Configuration and linked with commits and PR.

But after some days I started using Azure artifact for deployment and from that point "No workitems found to update" output came. I think this is the reason.

As Azure artifact is not supported work item view and in upcoming release I will change artifact type to confirm it.

Comment: Please validate my point @Leo and add your thoughts if required. Thank you

Comment: I want to correct my above statement based on validating above scenario.
So there is no issue with using Azure artifact but we should also include pipeline artifact before adding azure artifact and sequence also matters.

Comment: Tested with below scenarios:

1. If we add only Azure artifact in our pipeline which will not update work item status as It is not supported in case of azure artifact.

2. If we add azure artifact first and then we add pipeline artifact in case of utilizing pipeline artifact in Dev environment and using azure artifact in staging environment.
So this case also will not be able to update work item status.

3. If we add pipeline artifact first and then we add azure artifact, in this scenario it will update work item status.

Comment: Note: I am assuming we had properly linked commits and PR with work item and also configured workitem updater task in CD pipeline along with enabling "Automatically link work items included in this run" in CI pipeline